# get private property in Laravel Http in API Guzzle HTTP

Tags: php, laravel, api, http, guzzle

i want to store response data like private property to variable when called method

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

 public function myMethod(){
        $result = [];
        $response = Http::asForm()->withHeaders([
         'origin' => 'https://example.com',
         'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
         'referer' => 'https://example.com',
     ])->post('https://example.com', [
         'email' => 'example@gmail.com',
         'pass' => 'mypassword',
         'login' => 'Log+In',
         'withCredentials' => true, 
     ]);

     $result = $response;
     }
```

**Result** :

[image]

---

but i can't use keys in this result

Comment: use `$result = $response->json()` or `$result = $response->body()` within condition `$response->successful();`, check these in docs to know more

Comment: it's not working for private property :(

Comment: what is private in your question provide the complete code